# Weekly employee availability database design

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am designing a scheduling system for many employees to work around the clock from home. When a new event is scheduled by a user (1 hour long event, starting on the hour, 24 hour choices), the system needs to allow our users to select which employee they want to have work for them. I need to report who is available at that exact time. We have over 100 employees, and their availability changes frequently.

schedule table:
`EventID
EmployeeID

startTime (datetime)

endTime (datetime)`

availability table:

`EmployeeID

00:00

01:00

02:00

03:00

...

23:00`

Records in the availability table are stored as a varchar(7). Length of 7 is for each day of the week. Never available at this timeslot is '0000000'. Always available at this timeslot is '1111111'. Available only on Tuesday at this timeslot is '0010000'.

**EDIT:** this information is for one week, hence the 7 char length. From this week and into infinity, this table design assumes that the employee will be available at the same time each week (unless they are working). Of course, the employee can change their availability, and then the table can reflect those changes from that point forward. **/EDIT**

Finding out what employees are available at any given time requires a lot of looping which obviously bogs down the system and is not good for anyone.

This is the best way I have come up with to implement this system, short of possibly having a table to store each employee's availability. I realize mine is a terrible method. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a different table to store the employees' availability. I don't see why you shouldn't.

You should always avoid putting multiple data fields in one column (as your varchar column). I propose one row per employee, timeslot and day. That way you can speed up the queries a lot by indexing.

---

Even *if* you keep your ugly "everything-in-one-column approach" you should change to a CHAR because right now you're using up a byte per row just to keep the size of the column, even though it's always 7 chars long. Or even better, use a TINYINT (1 byte) and store the availability as binary flags. But of course, avoid this at all costs - you really do want to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database.

Comment: Great points. Do you mean create a new table for each employee's availability?

Comment: No, of course not. I mean one table for all employees' availability.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I understand your meaning. I currently have one table for availability of all employees. The event schedule is in a separate table. And BTW, I have changed to a CHAR datatype, thanks for the tip - but as you said, this is just a short term fix until I change the table setup!

Comment: I should analyze your comment more closely... you mentioned 'one row per employee, timeslot and day'. Do you mean having column names such as 'Mon_0800', 'Tue_0800', ..., 'Mon_0900', etc? This certainly beats my '7-character day of the week' method.

Comment: The best is to have a table with three columns: employee_id INT, timeslot TINYINT (can be 0-23), weekday TINYINT.

Comment: So each employee would have 7*24=168 rows in the table to hold their weekly recurring availability. I suppose a 4th column that held a boolean for whether or not the employee is actually available is necessary as well. Thanks! I'm giving it a try right now.

Comment: I've got it all set, it worked great. Much faster than my original method. My table setup is as follows:
`tutorID` int(8) NOT NULL, `day` char(3) NOT NULL, `timeslot_start` time NOT NULL, `timeslot_end` time NOT NULL, `avail` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'

THANKS A MILLION EVERYONE

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be better off storing each users availability, it's not actually that much data, plus you can expiring it once it's passed.:

```
create table employee (
  `id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

create table `employee_availability` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, KEY `employee`(`employee_id`),
  `start_time` DATETIME, KEY `start`(`start_time`),
  `end_time`   DATETIME, KEY `end`(`end_time`)
);


SELECT e.* FROM employee
  JOIN employee_availability ea ON ea.employee_id = e.id
WHERE NOW() between start_time and end_time
```

Comment: I completely understand your answer, thank you. I was not as clear as I should have been originally (question has been edited now), the availability will recur weekly. And I need to know when employees are available months in advance, so I cannot store this information as specific DATETIME data. I can't think of a way to do it, but would your advice be possible with just 'day of the week' and 'time' data as well? I don't know how I would build the SQL.

Comment: Hey Ben, I was just doing some estimation I think this answer will stil work.  Figuring your company has 150 employees, they're going to store 10 different availability times per day, for 56 days(8 weeks) that's 84000 different rows.  I don't imagine the query running slow at all.

Comment: Thanks Logan. I agree the query would not be a burden... but where would these 84000 rows come from? I cannot ask the employee to fill out their availability every week. If they specify their availability one single time, then that should be it. I see you solution as a parallel table to my (flawed) availability table, with a cron job running at the end of each week to populate your (better, faster) availability table. This would certainly reduce server load, but it has obvious data redundancy issues and still requires my original table to be in place.

Comment: The good thing with Logan's solution is that it's scalable for new features. If an employee is sick all you need to do is remove that day from the availability table. I agree that you would need either a cronjob or let the manager fill it up manually according to work schedules (in which case it becomes a GUI problem).

Comment: I like the flexibility of this method, but it just seems like a lot of things need to come together in order to make it work. Every week either the cron or the manager needs to make a fix. I want to set the system up so that once the data is in the table, no further tinkering is required. Maybe I just don't trust people/computers, but it seems like something is far more likely to wrong with this answer. Thanks so much for the suggestions.